Wrapping a number within a specific range
I have come across the below wrapping formula to wrap a number x within a range [min, max].
const wrappedValue = (x - min) % (max - min + 1) + min;

I am trying to understand the formula.
Specifically, I am not able to understand why we need to subtract min from x?
Why the below formula cannot be used? 
x % (max - min + 1) + min

Basically it ensures that the input number is returned if it's within the range, even if min is not a multiple of the range size. Both formulas can be used, they just have different application areas. You'll need to tell us where you came across this and how/where it is used if you want us to explain the why in context.

The two formulas don't produce the same result.

The first formula doesn't seem to work when x < min, the result can be out of the range.

it's shifting the range to start at 0. the % modulo operation wraps numbers around 0, is this required in javascript because in JS the % returns a remainder not a modulo, so this is the usual workaround.

@danielRICADO @Barmar In order to shift the range at 0, why we need to perform x-min? I am not able to understand this.

it is a little confusing, here is an article that explains in a bit more depth but in short it is a "bug" in javascript https://web.archive.org/web/20090717035140if_/javascript.about.com/od/problemsolving/a/modulobug.htm
